# How do I know when a child process died?

Tags: python, synchronization, ipc, process, multiprocessing

In my class I run 4 process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

    procs = (
             Process(target=ClassOne, name='ClassOne'),
             Process(target=ClassTwo, name='ClassTwo'),
             Process(target=ClassThree, name='ClassThree'),
             Process(target=ClassFour, name='ClassFour'),
            )

    for p in procs:
        p.daemon = False
        p.start()
```

I would like to be notified when one of my children process died so i can kill the other and my self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define a signal handler for **SIGCHLD**, inspect the frame returned by the just dead child to retrieve the information you need about it ... and if necessary exit() the parent too :)

Comment: @Spi, if you were looking for a Unix-specific solution you should have indicated this in the question.

Comment: @Constantin, Win does not have signals? I'm really curious, no polemic :)

Comment: Windows has a C signal API, but doesn't use them natively. In Windows, you can trivially wait on child process handles. You would simply wait for the first to become signalled, then terminate the others and then exit yourself.

Comment: Well, i guess your answer implies something like `signal.signal(SIGCHLD, handler)`. But http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html says "On Windows, signal() can only be called with SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGINT, SIGSEGV, or SIGTERM. A ValueError will be raised in any other case." No SIGCHLD.

Comment: @Constantin, you are right and I was not saing the opposite... I was asking you if and how signals are handled on Windows as I don't know ... @MSalters explained it very cleanly, thanks to him!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use `os.waitpid()` passing *-1* as the first argument and *0* as the second one.

- The first argument means that the request pertains to any child of the current process.
- The second argument means that it behaves as `wait()`.

The function returns a tuple with the pid of the dead child and its exit code.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look at the class AutoJoiningProcess in the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995419/in-python-how-do-i-know-when-a-process-is-finished).

If you're prepared to add to your code a dependency to gobject (part of PyGTK) then AutoJoiningProcess would allow you can listen to a signal that is emitted when a process finishes.  On that signal you could then respond however you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to explicitly wait until all processes are done.

```
while multiprocessing.active_children():
    pass
```

This is not event driven as you might intend, but it will get the job done in your example. Also make sure you `import multiprocessing`.

Comment: OP wants to terminate when *at least one* child dies, not when all of them die.

Comment: This solution will use one CPU for busy waiting and is no solution to the question as pointed out by @Constantin.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a Windows solution. It uses [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28VS.85%29.aspx) API call. For Unix [os.waitpid](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.waitpid) may do the job.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import ctypes


SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000
INFINITE = -1


def mbox(msg):
  ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, msg, u'spam', 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':

  # start 2 processes
  procs = [mp.Process(target=mbox, args=(msg,)) for msg in u'ab']
  for p in procs:
    p.start()

  # wait for at least one process to terminate
  handles = [
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, False, p.pid)
    for p in procs]
  array_type = ctypes.c_long * len(handles)
  handle_array = array_type(*handles)
  ctypes.windll.kernel32.WaitForMultipleObjects(
    len(handles), handle_array, False, INFINITE)

  # terminate the rest
  for p in procs:
    p.terminate()

  # exit
  print 'done'
```

Comment: The issue is that waitpid() takes only **one** pid and is blocking until timeout ... WaitForMultipleObjects() does the job as it can handle many objects at the same time... Can you provide a POC using waitpid() ?

Comment: @Spi, as you apparently found out yourself, `waitpid` can be used to wait for "i-dont-care-which-one" child to die. The problem is that you may have other children spawned and `waitpid` will signal their termination too...